# SQL Server drop table and delete data form file system

Tags: database

I wans to completely remove any data from the file system after a drop table.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Without telling the type of database or the standard(s) it adheres to, it is difficult to get more specific than *yes, probably*. While you are at it: there are typos in the title as well as in each and every sentence of your post but the last.

Comment: 1 - SQL server
2 - Yes, I have a one letter typo, "wans" should read "want", sorry can't find any more. 
While you are at it: "Each and every sentence ...but the last" is pretty funny, considering that the body of the post was two sentences...

Comment: `data form` in the title. And it would be easier to see *SQL Server* as the database type if the post was tagged [tag:sql-server], as well as addressing users interested in the area/product.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to FILESTREAM Data, you can execute

```
EXEC SP_FILESTREAM_FORCE_GARBAGE_COLLECTION
```

Actually you need to execute twice.

More info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/filestream-and-filetable-sp-filestream-force-garbage-collection?view=sql-server-ver16